my hp computer running windows says it's not activated but it should be
when I purchased my laptop it was activated and working fine. about 2 years later to right now it is saying my pc isn't activated. I go to my pc's activation settings says it's not activated so I click troubleshoot. when it completes is says :
"troubleshooting has completed"
"we found a windows 11 home digital license for this device running Windows 11 Home. to
activate using this digital license, select upgrade your edition of windows"
if i click that button it gives me a confirmation popup saying it will restart my pc and add features. i canceled it.
windows 11 came with the pc, it was new when I got it, I canceled it because I did not know what it would do
I don't know what to do so please help me

did you purchase the laptop new or used, and is it the original OS shipped with it? have you reached out to HP support? if its the original OS shipped with the device, then the OEM (HP) is obligated to provide licensing support

Why did you cancel it?

You should allow that process to continue. If it solves the problem: good. If it doesn't, come back and update your question with the outcome.
